# WSO2 Identity Server: Single Logout not sending to all Service Providers

Tags: java, xml, wso2, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I'm attempting to implement Single Logout using WSO2, but have hit a wall.

The initiating Service Provider is successfully able to send the logout request to the IdP (WSO2), and receive a logout-response. However, no other logged-in Service Providers are receiving the logout command from the IdP.

I've enabled Debug-level logging for the LogoutRequestSender class via the console, and I am seeing the following log: **"A logoutReqSenderTask is assigned to the thread pool"**.

Looking at the sourcecode for the LogoutRequestSender class, the private class "LogoutReqSenderTask" (which implements "Runnable") is supposed to create a debug-log with the value of the SAMLRequest:

```
public void run() {
    List<NameValuePair> logoutReqParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    // set the logout request
    logoutReqParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SAMLRequest", logoutReqDTO.getLogoutResponse()));

    if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        try {
            log.debug("SAMLRequest : " + SAMLSSOUtil.decodeForPost(logoutReqDTO.getLogoutResponse()));
        } catch (IdentityException e) {
            log.debug(e);
        }
    }
    //...snip...
}
```

However, this log is never getting written, indicating that this code is not being executed.

The only thought I've been able to come up with is that the "run" method is hitting an unhandled excpetion before it enters the first "try" of the method, and thus never gets to write the log (because this code is using an "ExecutorService" to queue the threads, unhandled exceptions will fail silently).

Here is a sample (anonymized) of the logout request that I am sending from my SP to the IdP:

```
<samlp:LogoutRequest 
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
    ID="S2E267375A5BFB18E3B54FE839AF43B2F84AAE1E7A" 
    Version="2.0" 
    IssueInstant="2015-05-13T20:19:41Z" 
    Destination="[SSO Server Location]">
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">[Issuer name]</saml:Issuer>
    <saml:NameID xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" NameQualifier="[SSO Server Location]">UserName</saml:NameID>
    <samlp:SessionIndex xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">d1b98786-f9d7-45dd-9712-a63f8f64cb02</samlp:SessionIndex>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Anything? From anyone?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm also hitting this wall, and it's hard finding any good information about WSO2's SLO procedure.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this issue, unfortunately. I've been trying to find a way around having to use SLO at all by managing timeouts between the application and the IdP, but I'm fairly certain I'll still have to get this working somehow.

Comment: This is strange. Which WSO2 Identity Server version are you trying with? And have you tried this in your local machine - IdP + SPs?

Comment: I was finally able to resolve this issue, though the logs I cited in my question are a little misleading. The issue was that the network-ports from WSO2 back to my Service Provider weren't open, and were also being blocked by Windows Firewall. Additionally, it turns out that "log.debug..." in the code-snippet above either never runs, or doesn't write to visible logs, even when the logout message is sent to secondary service providers (which is a bit of a red herring).